# Flipping Bit Errors

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

The caller wants us to answer the following 64 questions:

is base prime? is base + 1 prime? is base + 2 prime? is base + 3 prime? ... is base + 63 prime?

The function is supposed to build and return a 64-bit unsigned long long where each bit holds the answer to the corresponding question: bit #k of the return value tells whether base + k is a prime number.

Not sure where I went wrong here. The function should output 0x820A00A08800228AULL but I'm getting the 10004514. I thought to start with the MSB and shift left would build it bit by bit.

```
int prime( unsigned long long n ){
    int a;

    for( a = 2; a<=sqrt((double)n); a++ ){
        if( n%a == 0 )
            return 0;
    }
    if( a == n )
        return 1;
}

unsigned long long setPrimeBits( unsigned long long base ){
    int a;
    unsigned long long b = 0x000000000000000ULL;

    for( a=63; a>=0; a-- ){
        if( prime( base+a ) ){
            b |= 1;
            b = b<<1;
        }//end if
        else b = b<<1;
    }//end for
    return b;
}
```

Main & output as follows...

```
int main(){
    printf( "%16X\n", setPrimeBits( 100 ));
}
        10004514
```

Comment: This is the perfect moment to start using a debugger! To not say "*Not sure where I went wrong here.*" is a bad question, if ît even were a question at all.

Comment: Starting with the MSB but you're shifting left as you iterate.  Seems wrong.

Comment: Your prime() is kind of brute forcey.

Comment: If using VS, add a breakpoint and then interrogate a value.  Or put in a print statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `prime()` function exhibits undefined behavior. If it doesn't find a prime, the final conditional will also be false (because `a` is near the `sqrt(n)`, not near `n`), which means you will have no executed return statement. To fix this, Just `return 1` if you complete the for loop (that is, you find no prime divisors).
2. You want to print an `unsigned long long`. The format string for that is `%016llX`.
3. You shift `b` one too many times. Let's assume the last loop of the for loop (computing `a + 0`) is prime. You'll write that to the bottom bit, and then move it over one place.

Fixing these errors, we get some code that looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int prime( unsigned long long n ){
    int a;

    for(a = 2; a<=sqrt((double)n); a++)
        if( n%a == 0 )
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

unsigned long long setPrimeBits( unsigned long long base ){
    int a;
    unsigned long long b = 0x000000000000000ULL;

    for(a = 63; a >= 0; a--) {
        b = b << 1;
        if(prime(base+a))
            b |= 1;
    }

    return b;
}

int main(){
    printf( "%16llX\n", setPrimeBits( 100 ));
}
```

Which, when run, reports:

```
[12:54pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./pr 
820A00A08800228A
```

And, because there seems to be confusion about the left-shifting in other answers, you could write an equivalent `setPrimeBits()` that looks like this:

```
unsigned long long setPrimeBits( unsigned long long base ){
    int a;
    unsigned long long b = 0x000000000000000ULL;

    for(a = 0; a < 64; a++)
        if (prime(base+a))
            b |= (1ULL << a);           

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Looks like prime() could just return with no particular value at all (fall out of the routine).  That would give a random (?) or undefined value.

Comment: But when I tested it, it did work. I tested 121 and 0x198F5U.

Comment: @seeholz: Your prime function has undefined behavior. It can appear to work, but that doesn't mean it will always work. The fix I've shown here removes the undefined behavior.

Comment: `sqrt((double)n)` remains an issue.  On a typical machine, the conversion to `(double)` will truncate to 53ish significant bits, but `base` is 64`.  Quick suggestion: `unsigned long long limit = sqrt(n) + 1; for(a = 2; a<=limit; a++)`.  May have to ponder this deeper.

Comment: @chux: I imagine that seeholz could still satisfy the program requirements even if `prime()` only accepted `unsigned` arguments.

Comment: Agree that if `n` < sqrt(1e54) there should be no problem.  Further, `prime()` is not the focus of this posting and appears to be a placeholder code anyways.